# Position text slightly to the left or right of the center viewport

Tags: html, css, position, text-align

I have a very simple use case where I want to shift a block of text either slightly to the right or left of center in the viewport.

// html file

```
    <div>
      Hello
    </div>
```

// css file

```
body {
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
}
```

So this centers the text, but how do I move it slightly left or right of the center point.

Answer (score 0):

So the easiest way is to change the child elementś position to relative and then use the left property, either a minus value to move it the the left, i.e more left than center, or a positive. The default position property of all elements is static. So if you change it to relative then you can take control of the positions, here is the only veryl slightly modified css to acheive the result,

```
body {
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  left: -200px
}
```